# How to index a column in kusto query after pivot for azure log alerts

Tags: azure, logging, azure-data-explorer, alerts

I have the following kusto queury working as a log query in Azure

```
traces
| where message contains "SWSE"
| extend d=parse_json(message)
| extend Info=tostring(d.message)
| where Info startswith "Borrow Token" or Info startswith "Return Token" 
| extend  tAction = tostring( split(Info,' ',0)[0])
| summarize count_=count() by tAction, timebox=bin(timestamp, 10m)
| evaluate pivot(tAction,sum(count_))
| extend  diff = abs(Borrow-Return)
| where diff>2
```

resulting in

[image: Result of query in azure log explorer]

However, this line is marked as an error when it is imported into log alerts, not when it is run against the Azure logs.

```
| extend  diff = abs(Borrow-Return)
```

with the error:

```
The request had some invalid properties
```

Is there another way to reference these columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the output schema of the `pivot()` plugin is not deterministic and depends on the input data - you may need to use `column_ifexists()` for cases in which the column you expect actually don't exist in the output schema.

- doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/columnifexists

for example:

```
| extend diff = abs(column_ifexists("Borrow", 0) - column_ifexists("Return", 0))
```